# how to return value from a recursive function that includes fork()?

Tags: fork, return-value

There is a simple program in c which computes the maximum value in an int array. It uses fork() to do this job faster. In fact, it halves the array, and each part halves itself and so on.(something like merge sort.) the problem is that the lines after calling findMax function in main, are executed many times(number of child processes). and the return value is not correct. I think I must use wait() elsewhere, but I don't know where. can anybody help me?Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

int findMax(int a[], int l, int r);

int main(){
   int n;
   int max;
   int stat;
   int i;
   int arr[100];
   printf("Enter number of numbers:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   srand(time(0));
   printf("The array is:\n");
   for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        arr[i] = rand()%128;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   max = findMax(arr, 0, n-1);
   wait(&stat);
   printf("the entire maximum number is: %d\n", max);
   return 0;
    }

int findMax(int a[], int l, int r){
   int blockMax;
   int i;
   if(r-l+1<10){
        blockMax = a[l];
        for(i = l+1; i<=r; i++){
           if(a[i]>blockMax)
                blockMax = a[i];
        }
        printf("maximum from number %d to %d is  %d\nPID:%d PPID:%d\n", l+1, r+1, blockMax, (int)getpid(),  (int)getppid());
        return blockMax;
   }
   else{
        int m;
        int max1, max2;
        int status;
        m = (l+r)/2;
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid<0){
           printf("Fork failed.\n");
           return 0;
        }
        else if(pid == 0){
           max1 = findMax(a, l,m);
        }
    else{
       max2 = findMax(a, m+1, r);
    }
    wait(&status);
    if(max1 > max2)
       return max1;
    else
       return max2;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to share the values, you should be using threads, not processes.

Comment: But certainly there exists a solution. I'm sure about  the existence,but I don't know what's that!

Comment: Of course there is a solution. Inter-process communication. Existence of a solution does not imply reasonability of such solution though.

Comment: Except when you have to use such solution.

Comment: Why would you *have* to? Except in an exercise, which would be rather off-topic.